# mod_rewrite works for '/test', but not for '/'

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

The following code inside an .htaccess file is behaving incorrectly..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /test/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The above will correctly send requests to 'domain.com/uri-here' to the '/test/' directory.. However, requests to 'domain.com/' are not matched / routed.

I'm unsure if there's an issue with the environment, though it seems so due to same / similar code working on another server.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` is likely matching against `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`